# Docker, web app static files. Best practices?

Tags: django, docker, containers, web-deployment

How do people tend to handle static assets in web deployment on docker?

For example, in a django app deployed in a container, do you have the app server serve up the static files from the container, or do you sync them to another server for a webserver to serve, or do you use a CDN?

If not serving from the app container, when do you push files to CDN or webserver: as part of the container build, or as a second process in the build, and how do you ensure both steps stay in sync?

Comment: what a CMS has to do with hosting static files?

Comment: Hah typo, meant CDN, clearly

Comment: Why downvote? It's a legit question.

Comment: is your question really related to docker? why would you think best practices for static file hosting would be different using docker? Could you clarify

Comment: Yes actually. What I'm asking is how people tend to manage their static files in a container based architecture. The point of which is to have self contained deployments. To me it seems that you have a choice of either building twice (once in the container, once outside it to push the statics to the static server), or to serve from inside the built container. This is a situation which didn't exist with common deployment scenarios without docker.

Comment: SInce this question is still unanswered (despite this page saying there is is one answer, right now), I'll add the reason this is a good question is that ppl have to decide what technology to use to open the port to send the files through: you have to open a port in the container. Some use ngnx, others create custom stuff using Rust, go, python, etc. 

It's a good question and I don't think there is strong consensus, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a form of cloud storage to achieve that. S3 for example. You can also host your static files just like a CDN. Since you're using django, consider reading this [article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/). It explains how to host static files from within a django app.

As a Laravel user you could use Laravels built in [flysystem](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem) support.